# Probability distribution problem, "$n$ distinguishable particles are placed randomly into $N$ boxes"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $n$ distinguishable particles are placed randomly in $N$ boxes
(states).  A particular configuration of this system is such that there are $n_s$ particles in state $s$, where $1 \leq s \leq N$.  The ordering of the particles in any particular state does not matter. Show that the number of ways of realising a particular configuration is: $$W = n!\prod_{s = 1}^{N} \frac{1}{n_s!}$$

Hello once again StackExchange!

Can one provide me some insight into this question? I am unsure on how to tackle it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (Which is almost the answer):

Imagine the balls being all in a row, with boundaries between them (like in the balls and boxes problems in your handout). Then, there are $n!$ different ways of putting the discrete balls in a row changing their order. But within each box, you don't care about order. Hence you have to divide $n!$ by the permutations of the elements of each box.